# Setting HTTP response status and message in .NET7 API

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to set response HTTP code, and message manually in specific cases, from a controller.
So far, i have tried to achieve that with simple method:

```
 HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)statusCode;
 HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync("TEST");
```

But it doesn't work properly, since in swagger i can see an error message:

> Response body Unrecognized response type; displaying content as text.

Do You maybe have tips how to do that properly?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the test code below. If I have misunderstood your needs, you can tell me your needs and usage scenarios.

**Code**

```
    [HttpGet("Test")]
    public IActionResult Test(int statuscode)
    {
        int Code = statuscode;
        string Message = string.Empty;

        if (Code == 200)
        {
            Message = "Success";
        }
        else if (Code == 400)
        {
            Message = "Client Side Error";
        }
        else if (Code == 401)
        {
            Message = "UnAuth";
        }
        else if (Code == 500)
        {
            Message = "Internal server error";
        }
        return StatusCode(Code, Message);
    }
```

**Test Result**

[image]